# Unsatisfied with an answer

Tags: discussion, questions

I asked a question a while ago, about [performance problems](https://superuser.com/questions/896008/memory-not-unloading), but the question I was given didn't solve my problem, (it didn't even try), and now the question is closed.

The same situation is causing more problems again, but being the same situation, I can't re-ask the same question, but since the question was closed as "too broad" and I don't have anything new to add, (I thought I gave all the necessary information) I don't know how to deal with it. What can I do?

Comment: Editing the question would bring it back into the reopen queue - and if its still happening, its a *great* chance to add more detail about what you have tried so far. Something specific 'i'd suggest adding is how big these tiff files are, since this might be the common denominator here.

Comment: That's an interesting problem you have there.  I can't vote to reopen, but gave you an upvote.

Comment: @Ben: Please edit your question to show screenshots from the Processes tab of Task Manager and also from RAMMap as currently it is not possible to determine the source of the problem.